# Newbie going fishing in a lake. Which of these lures would be best?

Tags: gear, fishing, technique, lakes

I'm new to fishing and I'm going to try to visit a lake in an hour or so.

There are rumored to be pike, brasen, crucian carps and more types of carp too, eels and tench.

I heard there are plenty of tench. I'm hoping to catch pike, carps or tench. This is my selection of lures.

[image]

Which one would be best to start out with?

I think the water is murky, so the silvers are probably off the menu.

Comment: What area/lake are you going to be fishing in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with the 3 Mepps style lures, and the two spoons at the bottom left of the pic. They'll make more noise and vibrations than the others. The others looks to me to be fast retrieve lures which may certainly attract fish, but if the water is murky may be too fast for the fish to reliably catch up to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I caught a small one with one of the golden spoons on the bottom left. Lost the Moresilda to the tackle gods, unfortunately, though.

Comment: Were you trying to slow retrieve it or fast retrieve it?

Comment: I was trying both, but it got tangled up in a fallen tree in the lake because the wind swept my line over it when I was casting.

Comment: Ah, next time that seems to be happening, pull the lure back to you before it has a chance to hit the water. Put your hand on the reel to stop line going out, the the line taught a little then sweep the lure back with your rod. Be careful you don't swing it into your face though. After fishing for a while, you know a bad cast when it's happening and you just stop it midair before it ruins the fish or your lure gets caught. :-)